# C# Lambda Expression Summation Exception

Tags: c#

```
decimal val=dataRow.AsEnumerable().Sum(s=>s.Field<decimal>("Quantity"));
```

if column contain null it raises Exception.so i want to return zero instead of Exception

Answer (score 1):

according to the documentation http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360891(v=vs.110).aspx the Field extension of dataset already returns null for cases where the Value is null but it only supports nullable reference types. 
*it does not support nullable types like decimal?* It will throw an exception while parsing the decimal.

So you have to check against DBNull of the field manually and then cast it.
Usually it would return DBNull but the extension already handles that.

So you can simply check against Null within the linq expression like this

```
decimal val=dataRow.AsEnumerable().Sum(s=> s["Quantity"] == DBNull.Value ? 0M : s.Field<decimal>("Quantity"));
```

as posted by Dmytro Rudenko

Comment: Reading the spec, it says `Additionally, DataSet does not support nullable types. The Field method provides support for accessing columns as nullable types.` - so you can't have a nullable `decimal` in the `DataSet`, but you can call `Field<decimal?>` and it handles `DBNull` corectly. (`If the underlying value in the DataSet is DBNull.Value, the returned nullable type will have a value of null.`)

Comment: right, that makes sense, so you could actually check sum with `Sum(s => s.Field<decimal?>("Quantity") ?? 0);`

Answer (score 0):

try

```
decimal val=dataRow.AsEnumerable().Sum(s=>s.Field<decimal>("Quantity")??0);
```

Comment: I'd highly assume that `Field<decimal>` will return a `decimal` that can't be null anyway.

Comment: @user2674389 refer to MichaC 's answer

Comment: actually .Field<decimal>("Quantity") will return a parse exception if the value of the column is null, see my "new" answer...

Answer (score 0):

You could first parse the Field, then sum it:

```
decimal val = dataRow.AsEnumerable()
                     .Select(s => s.Field<decimal?>("Quantity"))
                     .Where(s => s != null)
                     .Sum(s => s) ?? 0.0m;
```

Please note that I used decimal?, so the code actually can handle nulls. Also I used the coalesce operator, because Sum will return null when the enumeration is empty.

Answer (score 0):

```
decimal val=dataRow.AsEnumerable().Sum(s=> s["Quantity"] == DBNull.Value ? 0M : s.Field<decimal>("Quantity"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
decimal val = dataRow.AsEnumerable().Sum(s =>
   {
      var field = s.Field<object>("Quantity");
      return field == null ? 0 : (decimal) field;
   });
```

but simplest way is just allow decimal to be nullable

```
decimal val = dataRow.AsEnumerable().Sum(s => s.Field<decimal?>("Quantity") ?? 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [spec](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383052.aspx) for `Enumerable.Sum<Nullable<decimal>>`,

> This method returns zero if *source* contains no elements.
>
> The result does not include values that are **null**.

Thus it would seem that all the null checks, coalsesces and conditionals people are using are unnecessary, and all you need is

```
decimal val = dataRow.AsEnumerable()
    .Sum(s=>s.Field<decimal?>("Quantity"))
    .Value;
```